# How to resolve Golang cannot find packages in golang.org/x/tools/go?

Tags: go, dockerfile

This issue just randomly appeared between builds and now even our production repo, which hasn't changed in months, gets this when building as well.  I've been stuck on this for a while. It does not happen on our local machines, only when using the dockerfile.

```
Step 30/73 : RUN go get -d ./...
 ---> Running in ca969a5fc165
[91msrc/golang.org/x/text/cmd/gotext/main.go:31:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil (from $GOROOT)
    /app/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil (from $GOPATH)
src/golang.org/x/text/message/pipeline/extract.go:23:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/tools/go/callgraph" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/callgraph (from $GOROOT)
    /app/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/callgraph (from $GOPATH)
src/golang.org/x/text/message/pipeline/extract.go:24:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/tools/go/callgraph/cha" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/callgraph/cha (from $GOROOT)
    /app/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/callgraph/cha (from $GOPATH)
src/golang.org/x/text/message/pipeline/extract.go:25:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/tools/go/loader" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/loader (from $GOROOT)
    /app/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/loader (from $GOPATH)
src/golang.org/x/text/message/pipeline/extract.go:26:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/tools/go/ssa" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/ssa (from $GOROOT)
    /app/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/ssa (from $GOPATH)
src/golang.org/x/text/message/pipeline/extract.go:27:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/tools/go/ssa/ssautil" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/ssa/ssautil (from $GOROOT)
    /app/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/ssa/ssautil (from $GOPATH)
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c go get -d ./...' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I've traced all these dependencies (minus the first) to a file in golang.org/x/text/message/pipeline/extract.go.  They are all listed there as imports.  Below are the relevant parts of our dockerfile

```
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y git-core
RUN yum install -y wget
RUN yum install -y gcc-c++ make
RUN yum install -y libaio
RUN yum install -y openssl-devel


# Install Go
RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://dl.google.com/go/go1.12.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf go1.12.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
RUN mv go /usr/local
RUN rm go1.12.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz

# Copy application files
COPY ./ /app
WORKDIR /app

# Configure paths for GOPATH and GOROOT
ENV GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
ENV GOPATH="/app"
ENV GOBIN="$GOPATH/bin"
ENV PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin"

# Install Go dependencies
RUN go get github.com/creack/pty
RUN go get -d -v ./...

RUN go install -v ./...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the fix was to change "go get -d -v ./..." to "go get"

Additionally, as to why this happened on our production build when no changes were made to it, we are not using any package versioning, and an external package was updated to cause this error.  So after some investigation we should probably use go modules to handle versioning.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen with folder or user permissions. The issue seem to be very intermittent in nature. The solution that worked for me was to go find those packages in your `GOROOT` or `GOPATH` directories and just manually delete them and then run `go get`. This seems to fix the issue for me